# Windows Runtime equivalent to the Silverlight PhoneSubtleBrush

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

In Silverlight there is the PhoneSubtleBrush which is the color used in the Mail app to display the message excerpt below the subject.

Is there something in the Windows Runtime API that has the same color as PhoneSubtleBrush?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's exactly the same but I've been using `ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle` so far.

Comment: This is what I am using as well, but the ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle makes the letters seem weird, a little bit too small and faint (on a WVGA device), which I cannot fix by changing the FontSize property.